# R markdown: Issue suppressing progress bar inside function called in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am including some R code in Rmarkdown, and I am trying to suppress the progress bar inside a function.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
func <- function(n){
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = n, style = 3)
  for(i in 1:n){
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
}
```

and I want to call the function in Rmarkdown like this:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, progress=FALSE}
func(10)
```
````

However, even if I set `progress = FALSE`, the progress bar still shows. Is there a way to suppress it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

````
```{r}
invisible(capture.output(func(10)))
```
````

which seems to deliver what you want.